# Touch and move finger up - Number increase, move down - opposite

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't understand one thing how to make the same system like in app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dgrees-celsius-fahrenheit/id707697403) when you touch screen and move finger up, then the number increases.

It looks like scroll view. Maybe I need to count y.position of view while scrolling.scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), then use [translationInView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView%3a) to find out how much the user's finger moved by, and update your views accordingly

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And handle it:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGFloat yMovement = [sender translationInView:sender.view].y;
    // Do something with the movement

    // Then reset the translation
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sender.view];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, with this I able to make this system.